# How can I make sure older messages received before newer messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue

An application receives updates from a messaging system; the messaging system uses multi-threading and message order is not respected. How can I ensure correct updating, if the app receives older messages after new ones?

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

> receives older messages after new ones

That's not possible in Kafka. Records within a single partition cannot be processed out of order unless you explicitly re-distribute the processing, manually in your consumer.